# How to debug phoenix framework's log error?

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am installing this pheonix web app: https://github.com/poanetwork/blockscout

after installed all the dependencies, I run this command ( following the document) :

```
$ mix phx.server
```

and got error:

```
$ iex -S mix phx.server
Erlang/OTP 25 [erts-13.1.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [ds:2:2:10] [async-threads:1] [jit:ns]

2022-12-13T04:25:43.083 [notice] Application ethereum_jsonrpc exited: EthereumJSONRPC.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: :worker
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :badarg}
            (poolboy 1.5.2) /opt/app/blockscout/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl:283: :poolboy.new_worker/1
            (poolboy 1.5.2) /opt/app/blockscout/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl:304: :poolboy.prepopulate/3
            (poolboy 1.5.2) /opt/app/blockscout/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl:153: :poolboy.init/3
            (stdlib 4.1.1) gen_server.erl:851: :gen_server.init_it/2
            (stdlib 4.1.1) gen_server.erl:814: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib 4.1.1) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
2022-12-13T04:25:43.106 [notice] Application poolboy exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.106 [notice] Application decorator exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.106 [notice] Application decimal exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.106 [notice] Application websocket_client exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.106 [notice] Application ex_abi exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.106 [notice] Application ex_keccak exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.106 [notice] Application rustler exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.107 [notice] Application timex exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.107 [notice] Application gettext exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.108 [notice] Application combine exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.110 [notice] Application tzdata exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.110 [notice] Application spandex_datadog exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.111 [notice] Application msgpax exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.111 [notice] Application spandex exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.111 [notice] Application plug exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.111 [notice] Application telemetry exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.112 [notice] Application plug_crypto exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.112 [notice] Application mime exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.112 [notice] Application eex exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.112 [notice] Application optimal exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.112 [notice] Application logger_file_backend exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.112 [notice] Application jason exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.112 [notice] Application httpoison exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.113 [notice] Application hackney exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.113 [notice] Application metrics exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.113 [notice] Application ssl_verify_fun exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.113 [notice] Application parse_trans exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.113 [notice] Application syntax_tools exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.113 [notice] Application mimerl exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.113 [notice] Application idna exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.113 [notice] Application unicode_util_compat exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.113 [notice] Application cowboy exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.114 [notice] Application ranch exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.114 [notice] Application cowlib exited: :stopped
2022-12-13T04:25:43.114 [notice] Application certifi exited: :stopped
** (Mix) Could not start application ethereum_jsonrpc: EthereumJSONRPC.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: :worker
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :badarg}
            (poolboy 1.5.2) /opt/app/blockscout/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl:283: :poolboy.new_worker/1
            (poolboy 1.5.2) /opt/app/blockscout/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl:304: :poolboy.prepopulate/3
            (poolboy 1.5.2) /opt/app/blockscout/deps/poolboy/src/poolboy.erl:153: :poolboy.init/3
            (stdlib 4.1.1) gen_server.erl:851: :gen_server.init_it/2
            (stdlib 4.1.1) gen_server.erl:814: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib 4.1.1) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

I found there is no stack trace for the source code, all the stack trace that can be seen is the dependencies'.

so my question is: how to know `which line of the source code` of this eror occured at?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happened before your application even attempted to start.

*ErlangVM* attempts to start all the applications yours depends on upfront, and the error

```
Application ethereum_jsonrpc exited:
     EthereumJSONRPC.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error:
       shutdown: failed to start child: :worker
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :badarg}
```

basically means that `ethereum_jsonrpc` application failed to start preventing `ErlangVM` from trying to start the main application. To narrow down the issue, one might try to start the failing `ethereum_jsonrpc` explicitly, e. g. from `iex` session with `Application.ensure_all_started(:ethereum_jsonrpc)` or with more explicit `EthereumJSONRPC.Application.start(:normal, [])`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it resolved.

finally I don't know which line of code failed.

## Solution

1.print many debug logs into the source code and guess in which step it failed.

```
+    IO.puts "== config: #{ inspect config}"
+    IO.puts "== rolling_window_opts: #{ inspect rolling_window_opts}"
```

and also, in pheonix framework, you can guess the source code file from its CalssName, e.g.

`EthereumJSONRPC.Application` maps to `apps/ethereum_jsonrpc/lib/ethereum_jsonrpc/application.ex`

2.change the logger level.

3.edit the `config/config.exs` file to enable DB log:

```
   database: database_api,
   hostname: hostname_api,
   // add this line of code
   show_sensitive_data_on_connection_error: true
```